# Show that $\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} {{\frac{p-1}{2}}\choose {i}}^2 x^{\frac{p-1}{2}-i}$ is separable

Tags: polynomials, discriminant

This is a problem occurs in my research. For any algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $p$. I want to show that $\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} {{\frac{p-1}{2}}\choose {i}}^2 x^{\frac{p-1}{2}-i}$ is a separable polynomial over this field. I am trying to prove that $p$ does not divide the discriminant of the polynomial. It seems like all the prime factors of the discriminant are less than $p$.

Comment: This should follow from the formula for your polynomial in terms of the Legendre polynomial of the same degree.

Comment: Doesn't an inseparable polynomial over a field of characteristic $p$ have to be a polynomial in $x^p$? Your polynomial has degree $(p-1)/2$, which is less than $p$.

Comment: As the OP explains, "separable" here has its other meaning,  "having distinct roots".  A separable *field extension* is one that can be obtained by adjoining roots of a separable polynomial.

Comment: As Noam Elkies pointed out, this summation is probably equal modulo p to the solution $u(x)$ of a linear ODE of order 2: $S:y''+a(x)y'+b(x)y=0$ for suitable functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$. If $u(x)$ had a double root, say at $x_0$, then $u(x_0)=0$ and $u'(x_0)=0$ would be a non-trivial solution to $S$ which contradicts the uniqueness of the solution. Of course, one has to make sure that the usual proof for the uniqueness goes through in charactersitic $p$, i.e., that there is no divsion by $p$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, an *irreducible* in char. $p$ is not separable iff it is a polynomial in $x^p$. For reducible polynomials there is no such constraint, e.g., $x^2$ is not separable in char. $p$ for $p > 2$ (also in char. 2, but there it is a polynomial in $x^p$).

Comment: See Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, Theorem 4.1c in Chapter V.

Comment: Hm, I wonder if the OP has the same application in mind (counting supersingular elliptic curves).

Comment: @KConrad: Thank you a lot. Actually, I am constructing a deformation for a family of Artin-Schreier curves with fixed genus to answer open question 1 on this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609657.pdf.  My deformation work if I can show that there is one root of $\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} {{\frac{p-1}{2}}\choose {i}}^2 x^{\frac{p-1}{2}-i}$  that is not a root of $\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-3}{2}} {{\frac{p-1}{2}}\choose {i}}{{\frac{p-1}{2}}\choose {i+1}} x^{\frac{p-1}{2}-i}$, so if the former polynomial is separable then it is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me elaborate on Noam D. Elkies' comment. If we denote $n=(p-1)/2$, the discriminant of this polynomial $g(x)$ is non-zero modulo $p$ if and only if the discriminant of Legendre's polynomial $f(x)=2^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2(x-1)^{n-k}(x+1)^k=2^{-n}(x-1)^ng((x+1)/(x-1))$ is non-zero modulo $p$ (the roots of $f$ and $g$ are obtained from each other by fractional linear functions, thus if $g$ has only simple roots, so does $f$ and vice versa). The discriminant of Legendre's polynomial and even of Jacobi's polynomial is known, see, for example, the formula on page 5 [here](http://inside.bard.edu/~cullinan/papers/legendre_submitted.pdf). Indeed the prime divisors do not exceed $2n<p$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but rather a reformulation. Write $\equiv_p$ for congruence mod $p$. Here $p$ is odd.

Start with $\binom{\frac{p-1}2}i\equiv_p\binom{2i}i4^{-i} \mod p$. If we drop $x^{\frac{p-1}2}$ and then replace $x^{-1}\rightarrow x$, and letting
$$f_p(x):=\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-1}2}\binom{\frac{p-1}2}i^2x^i,$$
the problem concerns $f_p(x)$ being "separable". Now, this is equivalent to showing that
$$f_p(x)\equiv_p\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-1}2}\binom{2i}i^216^{-i}x^i$$
is "separable". Of course, the same goes to
$$g_p(y):=\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-1}2}\binom{2i}i^2y^i.$$